# Why does detectMultiScale return no faces?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, face-detection

I try to use tutorial code [from opencv tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) to detect faces. All cascades are loaded properly but after calling

```
faceCascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20) );
```

I get no faces, that means faces.size() returns 0. 
Does anybody played with this code? Does it work? What could I have wrong?

Comment: If you solved this problem by yourself, it is suggested to answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As I have written Mar 28 '14 at 11:57 I have had a bug in part of code showing if cascade is loaded. It was not. XML files HAVE to be in prog dir
It is SOLVED

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo His post is actually intended as an answer. That's why he says SOLVED. "XML files HAVE to be in prog dir" I think is the solution he found.

Comment: @sashoalm I have to admit it is not clear at all whether this is the answer, but on a second thought, yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. Yes, the solution was to put xml files into program directory (folder).

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying minimum detected object size as (20,20). Maybe your image contains faces which are of much smaller size. Try changing it to smaller number.

This page explains various parameters of detectMultiScale function :

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but I played with various sizes, also I know suggested manual, as well as many others.  It is something strange with this call to detectMultiScale. I compiled the example code standalone and it works, after I moved .xml files to program dir. But when I use it in my own class as a method it doesn't work. I tried to change captured stream getting it from VideoCapture but also with no result. Perhaps .xml files are readed wrong. Do you know how to check it? THere is something more. I checked all methods I use in Python, and they are working.

Comment: ok, I used cascade.empty() method of CascadeClassifier class and it returns True. What then?

Comment: build code in debug mode and see if cascade file is parsed properly or not.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have had a bug in part of code showing if cascade is loaded. It was not. XML files HAVE to be in prog dir.